# SQL conditional logic on one field not affecting the grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
ID  ActionType  Quantity  Fee
1   Commission  1         10
1   Open        2         10
2   Commission  1         20
2   Close       3         20
3   Commission  1         30
3   Transfer    4         30
```

How do I group by the ID and choose the ActionType which is not Commission?

So I would like to end up with

```
ID  ActionType  Quantity  Fee
1   Open        3         20
2   Close       4         40
3   Transfer    5         60
```

I can work out the sum of quantity and fee by using sum over partition by ID but I can't figure out how to select the ActionType for the pair which isn't Commission.

Comment: wait, is where actiontype != 'Commission' not what you want?

Comment: No because I still need to sum the quantity and fee for those records where actiontype is Commission.  I just want to display ActionType as being the other record in the pair with the same ID. e.g. ID 1 should display ActionType as 'Open' but the quantity and fee should include the line where ActionType = 'Commission'

Comment: The question title is pretty poor but I couldn't think of a way of describing the problem

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select id,
    max(case 
            when actiontype = 'Commision'
                then null
            else actiontype
            end) actiontype,
    sum(quantity) quantity,
    sum(fee) fee
from t
group by id;
```

It takes max of all the actionTypes except Commision, along with other sums.

Comment: So this works for the example I gave but in my actual data set I have an extra 20 columns in the select and group by.  When I use MAX with a CASE statement as in your solution.  I see the Commission row but with ActionType as NULL.  Any ideas what might be causing that?

Comment: Can I see the query that you're using ( you can edit the question and add)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select t.id, sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(fee) as fee,
       max(case when ActionType <> 'Commission' then ActionType end) as ActionType
from t
group by t.id;
```

This returns *one* row that doesn't have `'Commission'`.  If you have multiple rows, then you should ask another question and specify what to do in that case.

Comment: So your solution works for my simplified example but not when I apply to a  data set with more columns.  I suppose I will have to create a new question with an example where your solution doesn't solve the problem I have.

Comment: @fujih . . . Exactly . . . new questions should be asked as new questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        ID,
         CASE WHEN ID = 1 Then 'Open' 
              WHEN Id = 2 then 'Close'
              When ID = 3 then 'Transfer' 
              else '' END AS ActionType,Sum(Quantity) as Quantity,sum(Fee)
 FROM Table_Name
Group by
ID,
CASE WHEN ID = 1 Then 'Open' 
              WHEN Id = 2 then 'Close'
              When ID = 3 then 'Transfer' 
              else '' END
```

Comment: Miss `FROM` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
from what i understand you are trying to change the action type to the same type as the same id and then group them by, so you can do something similar to below:

```
  WITH T2 AS
  (
    SELECT 
      [ID],
      [ActionType],
      SUM([Quantity]) AS [Quantity],
      SUM([Fee]) AS [Fee]
    FROM [TSQL2012].[dbo].[StackOverFlow_300]
    WHERE [ActionType] = 'Commission'
    GROUP BY [ID],[ActionType]
  )
  SELECT 
    T1.[ID],
    T1.[ActionType],
    SUM(T1.[Quantity]) + SUM(T2.[Quantity]) AS [Quantity],
    SUM(T1.[Fee]) + SUM(T2.[Fee]) AS [Fee]
  FROM [TSQL2012].[dbo].[StackOverFlow_300] T1
  LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID 
  GROUP BY T1.[ID],T1.[ActionType]
  HAVING T1.[ActionType] <> 'Commission';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.id , table1.ActionType, t.Fee , t.Quantity from
(select id , sum(fee) Fee , sum(quantity) Quantity from table1
group by id) t
inner join table1 on table1.id = t.id
where table1.actiontype <> 'Commission'
```

Just replace `table1` in query with your table name